# Bootstrap react Navbar

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I am trying to style the bootstrap navbar component in react. I am using css to do so, my problem is, when I styled my

```
<Navbar>
```

component as follows:

```
.navbar{
    background: var(--secondary);  /*fallback for old browsers */    
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, var(--primary), var(--third));  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  var(--primary), var(--third)); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    font-family: var(--fst-main);
    color: white;   
    min-height: 4rem;   
    max-height: 5vh;
```

The background color does not apply when navbar is untoggled on smaller screens. So the buttons aren't really visible.

I tried to find what class is responsible for that but without any luck.
Tried to set background color as !important - not working either
Tried to wrap it  but then have 2 layers of background and is not looking good for larger screens